# import font in css through font face

Tags: css, fonts

font is not working

**here is CSS code**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Soolidium', sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  src:url(http://localhost/changingCinema/font/Soolidium.ttf) format('truetype');
}

heading
        {
            float:left;
            width:100%;
            margin-bottom:10px;
            font-size:54px;
            font-family: 'Soolidium', sans-serif;}
```

**this is HTML**

```
<heading>My heading</heading>
```

only working when I install this font in my window otherwise not.

Help me plz fast thank you.

Comment: have you tried using relative URL?

Comment: check dev tools is the font has loaded successfully.

Comment: how can i check in css

Comment: i cant check in src:url its not showing anything rather than url

Comment: You need to generate all the other fonts: .eot, .woff, etc.  have a look at the font squirrel generator.  Also this question has been asked millions of times

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@font-face not working for my ttf font in all browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17234768/font-face-not-working-for-my-ttf-font-in-all-browsers)

Comment: ttf is supported on modern browsers. http://caniuse.com/#feat=ttf

Comment: Can you try to get http://localhost/changingCinema/font/Soolidium.ttf directly from the browser?

Comment: What do you mean not working? You can't accessed the font directly?

Comment: @Orland, ttf only doesn't seem to work in ie11 but I haven't checked in edge, although it does work in ff and chrome, perhaps just include the eot version for crappy ie then?

Comment: @Orland i can access its shows to save file and its mean that the URL is write 
dont ask me stupid questions if you have solution so tell me. ok im not new in web development.

Comment: @RajnishRajput We don't have a clear picture of your setup, so how come that those are stupid questions? You're so rude. Why don't you upload everything so that we can reproduce it on our machines and that way we'll be able to help.

Comment: how can i upload my fonts here

Answer (score 0):

In Font face set font family name

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Soolidium';
  font-style: normal;
  src: url('http://localhost/changingCinema/font/Soolidium.ttf') format('truetype'); 
  }
```

For all browser support you have to give url from different font file.
(.eot/.woff/.ttf/.svg)

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure you put your @font-face before any other styles.

If possible you might also need to add additional rules for browser support like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Soolidium', sans-serif;
    src: url('Soolidium.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('Soolidium.woff') format('woff'),
    url('Soolidium.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

And as always check for spelling errors or pointing to the wrong path. 
**Remember** you are calling this from your CSS file so you need to point relatively to the font folder.

Answer (score -2):

Try replacing:

```
src:url(http://localhost/changingCinema/font/Soolidium.ttf) format('truetype');
```

with:

```
src: url('../font/Soolidium.ttf');
```

Assuming you have a folder named 'font' in your root directory with the font 'Soolidium.ttf' in.

Comment: how could you come up with that given that you don't know the file structure yet?

Comment: How are your files set up?

Comment: what you are looking for

Comment: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator Try this and generate all the other fonts then use the css code that it uses. And set up the file system the same